# Convert byte array to pdf

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

I am generating a .pdf file in an asp.net/c# enviroment. Then I convert the file to byte[] and send it to Dynamics AX. 
Is there a way to convert the byte[] back to .pdf and save it as DocuRef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save it as a file and reference it via a `DocuRef` record then just recreate the file on a network share or something similar via .NET (e.g. using [System.IO.FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: See this how to use a MemoryStream: http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2011/10/binary-data-in-ax2012/